# knockout.js observableArray changes not reflecting in UI

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

This is my model

```
var ViewModel =
{
    results_page: ko.observableArray(),
    show_result: ko.observable(true),
    load_page: function (data, event) { setupPage(event.currentTarget.children[0].innerHTML) }
}
```

I'm using observableArray to populate the following list from data.

```
function setupPage(page_index) {

    //some code goes here

    $.get(url, function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        if (data.result || false) {    
            ViewModel.results_page([]);
            var page = [];
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {    

                    //some code goes here

                    page.push(result[i]);                   
                }
            }
            ViewModel.results_page(page);      
        }
    });
}

<ul id="results" data-bind="visible: show_result, foreach: results_page">
    <li style="margin-top: 0px; cursor: pointer;">
        <span class="divider marker">
            <img alt="" data-bind="attr:{src:'/images/markers/' + $index() + '-green.png'}">
        </span>
        <a data-bind="text: description"></a>
        <span data-bind="text: distance + ' mi.'"></span>
        <p data-bind="text: address"></p>
        <p data-bind="text: city + ', ' + province"></p>
        <span class="divider arrow">
            <span>»</span>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and using this list to trigger paging

```
<ol data-bind="foreach: new Array(pages_count())">
    <li data-bind="click: $root.load_page">
        <a data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

It update the view with change in result_page for first request but after that it do not update view when result_page changes. I have tried to find some answer but no luck so far.

I'm new to knockout so let me know if there are scope of improvements.

Comment: What doesn't update?  The number of pages?

Comment: No number of pages do not change for some data, result list with foreach: results_page binding is not updated.

Comment: Which binding isn't working?  The <ul> binding or the <ol> binding?

Comment: <ul> binding is not working

Comment: Does the `if (result.data)` test pass for the second run through?

Comment: A minor code style point: the `i` variable in that for loop looks like it is a global. Could break if you have nested for loops trying to use the same `i`.

Comment: yes if (data.result || false) test is pass for every run also I have checked ViewModel.results_page after ViewModel.results_page([]) and ViewModel.results_page(page). It is getting right values but <ul> is not updating.

Comment: no there are not any nested loop but I changed the code to include var and still no effect.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this? Perhaps replacing the `$.get` with a simple `setTimeout` with some dummy data for testing purposes? Also this part `foreach: new Array(pages_count())` is really ugly. Can't you add a property (maybe even a computed property) to your VM for this?

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to change the `description` property under `results_page` and it doesn't show the change?

Comment: You are databinding to new Array(...).  This value is not observable.  No matter what you do later to modify the model behind the scenes, you will only see the data that was present in pages_count() at the time binding took place.  If you can, add a jsfiddle (replace your ajax call with something that generates random data) so we can help you further.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "It update the ul with change in result_page for first request but after that it only add and remove li from ul" That sounds exactly like the correct behavior. After the first run, Knockout will add new array items to the DOM and delete DOM items associated with deleted array items. Knockout will not redo the entire DOM structure within the foreach each time a new item is added to the array. For example, if you simply add an item to the array, Knockout will just add a new DOM item associated with the new array time and not rebuild the entire structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure that your server side code is returning correct data.
Open any browser's js debugger and look at errors.

I'm not sure what exactly wrong with your code, but I'm made simplified version which works almost the same way as yours. I hope it will help to understand your problem.

HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="visible: results_page().length > 0, foreach: results_page">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: description"></span>
    </li>
</ul>

<ol data-bind="foreach: pages_count()">
    <li data-bind="click: $root.load_page.bind($data, $index() + 1)">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

JS:

```
var ViewModel = {
    results_page: ko.observableArray(),
    show_result: ko.observable(false),
    load_page: function(pageIndex, test) {
        // load data by jquery...
        var pageData = [
            { description: 'description 1 of page ' + pageIndex },
            { description: 'description 2 of page ' + pageIndex }
        ];

        ViewModel.results_page(pageData);
        ViewModel.show_result(pageData.length > 0)
    },
    pages_count: function() {
        return new Array(3);
    }
} 

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4JVP2/2/)